# Weird, unexpected output in Bash Script with Perl

Tags: bash, perl, shell

I'm trying to write a Bash script that will be run in a folder containing multiple C source files.  One of these will contain main(), and will also contain a multiline comment at the top that describes the file/program and its features.

What I have so far is:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Grepping for main *.c file"
file=$(grep -l main *.c)
echo "the file is ${file}"
comment=$(perl -lne 'print if (/\/\*/ .. /\*\//)' ${file})
echo ${comment}
```

Which tells me which file contains the main() (in the test case, it's main.c).  The perl function then outputs (what I think to be) incorrectly.  Instead of just searching in the file, it outputs

```
Grepping for main *.c file
the file is main.c
/$RECYCLE.BIN /Applications /Backup /Extra /Extra (from old Mac) 2 /Library /Network /OS X Install Data /System /System Volume Information /Users /Volumes /bin /boot CMakeLists.txt build comment.sh main.c main.dSYM makefile tasksheet.pdf Student Number: n9999999 CMakeLists.txt a1_n9999999 build comment.sh main.c main.dSYM makefile tasksheet.pdf...
```

followed by the titles of the contents of the folder, with the actual multiline comment scattered throughout the output.

If I try and `cat main.c` it outputs correctly, but if in the bash script I do echo `cat main.c` or `cat ${file}` i get a similar type of garbage output.  What is causing it?  I have a feeling it is to do with the fact that a multiline comment contains /*, which in Unix is 'everything in the root directory', but is there a way around this?

Edit: Running that perl command `perl -lne 'print if (/\/\*/ .. /\*\//)' main.c` in the terminal outputs the intended result.

Comment: `cat main.c` from the script gives different results than `cat main.c` from the command-line?  If so, something is very wrong here; I suspect missing information in the question.

Comment: @ash
`Davids-Mac-Pro:Assignment 1 David$ cat main.c
/*
** Student Number: n90000000
** Name: David
** Extra functionality:
** List of functionality.
*/


// Standard Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>`


With a bash script containing `echo $(cat main.c)`:

`/$RECYCLE.BIN /Applications /Backup (redacted) CMakeLists.txt a1_n9999999 build comment.sh main.c main.dSYM makefile tasksheet.pdf Student Number: (redacted) List of functionality. build/ main.dSYM/ // Standard Includes #include <stdio.h> #include <stdbool.h> #include <string.h>`

Comment: Note that the test for `main` is not really sensitive enough.  A file containing the word `remaining` or any of the many other words containing the sequence of letters m-a-i-n will be matched.  However, that's largely tangential to the issue at hand.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not very good with grep.  Any hints as to how to make the test more robust?

Comment: The most fundamental step would be `grep -l -w main` to search for the word 'main'.  However, that would pick up 'the main idea is …' and so on, in a comment.  I'd probably exploit knowledge of how you format your `main()` function, using `grep -l -E '^int main\((void|int argc, char \*\*argv)\)$` to pick up either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` — they're the only signatures I ever use, and I keep the type on the same line as the function.  If you put the `int` on the previous line, drop `int` from the match.  You might still run into a 'main in a comment' problem, but…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double quote the echo:

```
echo "${comment}"
```

You're seeing the expansion of the `/*` into the list of files in your root directory.

(And that's a lot of debris in your root directory that shouldn't be there.  You shouldn't be able to write files in the `/` directory.  You need to worry about how you are (mis)using root privileges.)

---

Note that the test for `main` is not really sensitive enough. A file containing the word remaining or any of the many other words containing the sequence of letters m-a-i-n will be matched. However, that's largely tangential to the issue at hand.

> I'm not very good with grep. Any hints as to how to make the test more robust?

The most fundamental step would be `grep -l -w main` to search for the word 'main'.  However, that would pick up 'the main idea is …' and so on, in a comment.  I'd probably exploit knowledge of how you format your `main()` function, using `grep -l -E '^int main\((void|int argc, char \*\*argv)\)$` to pick up either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` — they're the only signatures I ever use, and I keep the type on the same line as the function.  If you put the `int` on the previous line, drop `int` from the match; if you have the open brace on the same line, modify the pattern to allow for, or require, that layout; etc.  You might still run into a 'main in a comment' problem, but it's pretty unlikely.

I also note that the Perl will pick up each block comment in each file, rather than stopping at the end of the first one.  You shouldn't have a single comment in most source files.  I think you can fix that with:

```
perl -ne 'if (/\/\*/ .. /\*\//) { print if ($comment == 0); } ++$comment if m/\*\//;'
```

I tried a more compact notation:

```
perl -lne 'print if (/\/\*/ .. /\*\// && $comment == 0); ++$comment if m/\*\//'
```

and a number of variants on this theme and the `&& $comment == 0` condition was functionally ignored.  The alternative shown above worked.

---

Curiosity got the better of me.  Using the 'Deparse' module (SO search '`[perl] deparse`') and applying it shows:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -lne 'print if (/\/\*/ .. /\*\// && $comment == 0); ++$comment if m/\*\//'
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    print $_ if m[/\*] .. m[\*/] && $comment == 0;
    ++$comment if m[\*/];
}
-e syntax OK
$ perl -MO=Deparse -lne 'print if ((/\/\*/ .. /\*\//) && $comment == 0); ++$comment if m/\*\//'
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    print $_ if m[/\*] .. m[\*/] and $comment == 0;
    ++$comment if m[\*/];
}
-e syntax OK
$ perl -lne 'print if ((/\/\*/ .. /\*\//) && $comment == 0); ++$comment if m/\*\//'  e2big.c
/* SO 18559403: How big an argument list is allowed */
$
```

The precedence of `&&` is high; that of `and` is low.  If you're using the range operator `..`, be cautious and use copious parentheses in the correct places.

Comment: this fixed it.  I will accept it as the answer as soon as it will let me.